# Requests to tesla inventory api timeout with request.get in python

Tags: python, timeout, web-crawler

I am writing a python web crawler to Tesla inventory with

```
url = "https://www.tesla.com/inventory/api/v1/inventory-results?query={%22query%22:{%22model%22:%22my%22,%22condition%22:%22new%22,%22options%22:{%22TRIM%22:[%22LRAWD%22],%22AUTOPILOT%22:[%22AUTOPILOT%22]},%22arrangeby%22:%22Price%22,%22order%22:%22asc%22,%22market%22:%22US%22,%22language%22:%22en%22,%22super_region%22:%22north%20america%22,%22lng%22:-122.1257,%22lat%22:47.6722,%22zip%22:%2294401%22,%22range%22:100},%22offset%22:0,%22count%22:50,%22outsideOffset%22:0,%22outsideSearch%22:false}"
resp = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
```

and I always got timeout error. However, when I paste the url to my chrome browser, I can get the response in json format very fast. I am wondering what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

even with a basic user agent I get `200`, a json with 55 matched.

```py
from pprint import pp
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = "https://www.tesla.com/inventory/api/v1/inventory-results?query={%22query%22:{%22model%22:%22my%22,%22condition%22:%22new%22,%22options%22:{%22TRIM%22:[%22LRAWD%22],%22AUTOPILOT%22:[%22AUTOPILOT%22]},%22arrangeby%22:%22Price%22,%22order%22:%22asc%22,%22market%22:%22US%22,%22language%22:%22en%22,%22super_region%22:%22north%20america%22,%22lng%22:-122.1257,%22lat%22:47.6722,%22zip%22:%2294401%22,%22range%22:100},%22offset%22:0,%22count%22:50,%22outsideOffset%22:0,%22outsideSearch%22:false}"
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
print(resp)
pp(resp.json(), depth=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Try with header:

```
 headers = {
        'authority': 'www.tesla.com',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-language': 'pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,tr-TR;q=0.6,tr;q=0.5',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried by putting the header but it doesn't work for me (timeout) I could guarantee that it still works for you

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"',
'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1'}
try:
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.text)
```